# installing liblinear in octave on windows

Tags: octave

i am trying to install liblinear 1.91 in octave 3.6.2 on windows 7.
octave is a clean mingw install without extra packages except for libsvm 3.12.
please note libsvm installed without a problem by running make.m from octave.
however when i try the same for liblinear i get:

> ../blas.o: In function `dscal_':
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../blas/dscal.c:4: multiple definition of`dscal_'
>   ../blas.o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../blas/dscal.c:4: first defined here
>   ../blas.o: In function `dscal_':
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../blas/dscal.c:4: multiple definition of`dscal_'
>   ../blas.o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../blas/dscal.c:4: first defined here
>   ../blas.o: In function `dscal_':
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../blas/dscal.c:4: multiple definition of`dscal_'
>   ../blas.o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../blas/dscal.c:4: first defined here
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:35: multiple definition of `TRON::info(char const*, ...)'
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:35: first defined here
>   ...o: In function`TRON':
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:44: multiple definition of `TRON::TRON(function const*, double, int)'
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:44: first defined here
>   ...o: In function`~TRON':
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:54: multiple definition of `TRON::~TRON()'
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:54: first defined here
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:161: multiple definition of`TRON::trcg(double, double*, double*, doubl
>   e*)'
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:161: first defined here
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:57: multiple definition of `TRON::tron(double*)'
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:57: first defined here
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:224: multiple definition of`TRON::norm_inf(int, double*)'
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:224: first defined here
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:234: multiple definition of `TRON::set_print_string(void (*)(char const
>   *))'
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:234: first defined here
>   ...o: In function`TRON':
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:44: multiple definition of `TRON::TRON(function const*, double, int)'
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:44: first defined here
>   ...o: In function`~TRON':
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:54: multiple definition of `TRON::~TRON()'
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:54: first defined here
>   train.o: In function`do_cross_validation':
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/train.c:86: undefined reference to `cross_validation'
>   train.o: In function`parse_command_line':
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/train.c:212: undefined reference to `set_print_string_function'
>   train.o: In function`mexFunction':
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/train.c:374: undefined reference to `check_parameter'
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/train.c:380: undefined reference to`destroy_param'
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/train.c:368: undefined reference to `destroy_param'
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/train.c:357: undefined reference to`destroy_param'
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/train.c:405: undefined reference to `destroy_param'
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/train.c:399: undefined reference to`train'
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/train.c:403: undefined reference to `free_and_destroy_model'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x166): undefined reference to`dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x188): undefined reference to `ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x1da): undefined reference to`ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x209): undefined reference to `daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x220): undefined reference to`dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x261): undefined reference to `daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x279): undefined reference to`ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x2c5): undefined reference to `daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x2dd): undefined reference to`dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x368): undefined reference to `daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x387): undefined reference to`ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x3aa): undefined reference to `ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x3c6): undefined reference to`ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x440): undefined reference to `daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x46e): undefined reference to`daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x5df): undefined reference to `dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x754): undefined reference to`daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x78f): undefined reference to `ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x7ca): undefined reference to`ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x828): undefined reference to `dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0xaf2): undefined reference to`dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x166): undefined reference to `dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x188): undefined reference to`ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x1da): undefined reference to `ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x209): undefined reference to`daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x220): undefined reference to `dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x261): undefined reference to`daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x279): undefined reference to `ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x2c5): undefined reference to`daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x2dd): undefined reference to `dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x368): undefined reference to`daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x387): undefined reference to `ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x3aa): undefined reference to`ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x3c6): undefined reference to `ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x440): undefined reference to`daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x46e): undefined reference to `daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x5df): undefined reference to`dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x754): undefined reference to `daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x78f): undefined reference to`ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x7ca): undefined reference to `ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x828): undefined reference to`dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0xaf2): undefined reference to `dnrm2_'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   warning: unable to find mkoctfile in expected location:`C:\Octave\Octave3.6.2_gcc4.6.2\bin\mkoctfile-3.6.2'
>   warning: mkoctfile exited with failure status
>   ../blas.o: In function `dscal_':
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../blas/dscal.c:4: multiple definition of`dscal_'
>   ../blas.o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../blas/dscal.c:4: first defined here
>   ../blas.o: In function `dscal_':
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../blas/dscal.c:4: multiple definition of`dscal_'
>   ../blas.o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../blas/dscal.c:4: first defined here
>   ../blas.o: In function `dscal_':
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../blas/dscal.c:4: multiple definition of`dscal_'
>   ../blas.o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../blas/dscal.c:4: first defined here
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:35: multiple definition of `TRON::info(char const*, ...)'
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:35: first defined here
>   ...o: In function`TRON':
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:44: multiple definition of `TRON::TRON(function const*, double, int)'
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:44: first defined here
>   ...o: In function`~TRON':
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:54: multiple definition of `TRON::~TRON()'
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:54: first defined here
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:161: multiple definition of`TRON::trcg(double, double*, double*, doubl
>   e*)'
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:161: first defined here
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:57: multiple definition of `TRON::tron(double*)'
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:57: first defined here
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:224: multiple definition of`TRON::norm_inf(int, double*)'
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:224: first defined here
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:234: multiple definition of `TRON::set_print_string(void (*)(char const
>   *))'
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:234: first defined here
>   ...o: In function`TRON':
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:44: multiple definition of `TRON::TRON(function const*, double, int)'
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:44: first defined here
>   ...o: In function`~TRON':
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:54: multiple definition of `TRON::~TRON()'
>   ...o:C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/../tron.cpp:54: first defined here
>   predict.o: In function`do_predict':
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/predict.c:71: undefined reference to `get_nr_class'
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/predict.c:81: undefined reference to`get_nr_feature'
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/predict.c:147: undefined reference to `predict_probability'
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/predict.c:155: undefined reference to`predict_values'
>   predict.o: In function `mexFunction':
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/predict.c:288: undefined reference to`free_and_destroy_model'
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/predict.c:312: undefined reference to `free_and_destroy_model'
>   C:\Octave\liblinear-1.91\matlab/predict.c:295: undefined reference to`check_probability_model'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x166): undefined reference to `dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x188): undefined reference to`ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x1da): undefined reference to `ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x209): undefined reference to`daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x220): undefined reference to `dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x261): undefined reference to`daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x279): undefined reference to `ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x2c5): undefined reference to`daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x2dd): undefined reference to `dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x368): undefined reference to`daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x387): undefined reference to `ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x3aa): undefined reference to`ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x3c6): undefined reference to `ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x440): undefined reference to`daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x46e): undefined reference to `daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x5df): undefined reference to`dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x754): undefined reference to `daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x78f): undefined reference to`ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x7ca): undefined reference to `ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x828): undefined reference to`dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0xaf2): undefined reference to `dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x166): undefined reference to`dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x188): undefined reference to `ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x1da): undefined reference to`ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x209): undefined reference to `daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x220): undefined reference to`dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x261): undefined reference to `daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x279): undefined reference to`ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x2c5): undefined reference to `daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x2dd): undefined reference to`dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x368): undefined reference to `daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x387): undefined reference to`ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x3aa): undefined reference to `ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x3c6): undefined reference to`ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x440): undefined reference to `daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x46e): undefined reference to`daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x5df): undefined reference to `dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x754): undefined reference to`daxpy_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x78f): undefined reference to `ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x7ca): undefined reference to`ddot_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0x828): undefined reference to `dnrm2_'
>   ...o:tron.cpp:(.text+0xaf2): undefined reference to`dnrm2_'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   warning: unable to find mkoctfile in expected location: `C:\Octave\Octave3.6.2_gcc4.6.2\bin\mkoctfile-3.6.2'
>   warning: mkoctfile exited with failure status

please help.

Comment: did you try to ask the liblinear developers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

starting from the liblinear-1.91/matlab folder, this compiles for me:

```
cd ..
mex   -c linear.cpp
mex   -c tron.cpp
cd blas
mex   -c *.c
cd ../matlab
mex libsvmread.c
mex libsvmwrite.c
mex train.c linear_model_matlab.c ../linear.o ../tron.o ../blas/*.o
mex predict.c linear_model_matlab.c ../linear.o ../tron.o ../blas/*.o
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using octave 3.6.2 with Visual Studio 2010.

I first followed the instructions here to get libsvm working: http://flyingpies.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/getting-libsvm-to-work-with-octave-on-windows/

To get liblinear compiled, run octave with visual studio environment variables (see link above), cd to the liblinear directory, and run these commands:

```
mex -c 'linear.cpp' 
mex -c 'tron.cpp' 
cd blas
mex -c 'daxpy.c' 
mex -c 'ddot.c' 
mex -c 'dnrm2.c' 
mex -c 'dscal.c'
cd ..\matlab 
mex -DMX_API_VER=0x07030000 -c linear_model_matlab.c -I..\\ 
mex -DMX_API_VER=0x07030000 train.c -I..\\ '..\tron.o' '..\linear.o' 'linear_model_matlab.o' '..\blas\daxpy.o' '..\blas\ddot.o' '..\blas\dnrm2.o' '..\blas\dscal.o' 
mex -DMX_API_VER=0x07030000 predict.c -I..\\ '..\tron.o' '..\linear.o' 'linear_model_matlab.o' '..\blas\daxpy.o' '..\blas\ddot.o' '..\blas\dnrm2.o' '..\blas\dscal.o' 
mex -DMX_API_VER=0x07030000 libsvmread.c 
mex -DMX_API_VER=0x07030000 libsvmwrite.c
```